Identify this movie involving a translator for deaf people
I saw a scene of a movie once that had a really nice song, but I do not know the name of the song nor the movie. Unfortunately, it has been a while and I do not remember the lyrics of the song either, but I do remember the scene.
Can you guys help me find the movie so I can hear the song again.
The scene goes like this:
A girl answers a Skype Video Call from a guy. The girl is sort of a translator for deaf people. This guy that calls is deaf and he wants her to translate for him. sign language. The call goes on but then they end up talking to each other, and the girl asks the guy what does he do, then he says he is a Comic Artist and shows her some of his drawings. The drawings are really good and the girl does not seem to believe that he drew them, so he says that he will prove to her that it is him that drew them. He picks up his pencil and paper and begins to draw. He is drawing the girl off of his monitor. Then this is where the songs starts to play. I really liked the song.The song plays out as he is drawing the girl. When he is done drawing, he shows it to the girl and she is amazed. 
This is all I can remember from the movie scene. Can anyone help me find the movie. Please.
Thank you all.

Since this is the OP's first post, and a lot of detail was put into the question, downvoters should have the courtesy to leave a comment on how they think the post could be improved.

I think you are looking for the movie The Little Death
There is a scene with a 'translator' like you described:

The final segment, involving a hearing-impaired video translator who makes a sex call for a deaf client, is another highlight. There’s sweetness within the smut and that’s not an easy achievement, especially when the director almost kills his own climax (so to speak) with a very cheesy song.

Source: The Guardian
You can see parts of the scene in the following trailer (at around 0:49) 



The song you are looking for should be "Light" from "Sleeping At Last"




Yes, that was the Movie. And the Song.
Thank you very much.

@JaimeT You are welcome, please accept the answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark
